# DynamoDB - boto3 - batch_write_item: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

This issue has been raised before but so far I couldn't find a solution that worked in boto3. GSI is set on 'solutionId' and partition key being 'emp_id'. Basically, I just want to delete all records in the table without deleting the table itself. What am I missing here?

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item

```
table_name = "solutions"
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
dynamodb_resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb_resource.Table(table_name)

data = table.scan()

delete_list = []
for item in data['Items']:
    delete_list.append({
        'DeleteRequest': {
            'Key': {
                'solutionId': {"S": f'{item["solutionId"]}'}
            }
        }
        }
    )


def list_spliter(list, size):
    return (list[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(list), size))


for batch in list_spliter(delete_list, 25):

    dynamodb_resource.batch_write_item(RequestItems={
        f'{table_name}': batch
    }
    )
```

Comment: You need to indicate the full primary key of each item, to include both partition key and sort key. Also, I think you need to use: `"key" : "value"` rather than `"key": {"S": "value"}` for the keys as this is higher-level interface which auto-marshalls Python native types.

Comment: @jarmod You mean this as below: (Same error)
delete_list.append(
        {
        'DeleteRequest': {
            'Key': {
                "solutionId": item["solutionId"]
            }
         }
        }
    )

Comment: @jarmod please post your answer. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two small issues here:

1. you're using the high-level [service resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#service-resource) interface so you don't need to explicitly tell DynamoDB what the attribute types are. They are inferred through automatic marshaling. So you can simply use `"key" : "value"` rather than `"key": {"S": "value"}` for the string keys
2. when deleting an item you need to provide the full primary key, to include both partition key and sort key

So, for example, if your partition and sort keys are named `pk` and `sk`:

```
'DeleteRequest': {
    'Key': {
        'pk': pk,
        'sk': sk
    }
}
```